# Readfile displays content

Tags: php, readfile

When i use following headers, IE7 shows me the content of the file, not a download prompt.
I searched al over google but didn't find an expanation.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"Copy van '.basename($file).'\"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: Do the headers actually work? Check with `wget -S` or `curl`

Comment: Didn't check. But can you give som more explenation about `wget`? Never heard before...

Comment: See [Headers already sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: Found it! I had al lot of code (html & javascript etc) before i tried to send the headers. NOT GOOD ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to send headers, be sure they are the first output of your script.

this won't work:

```
<html>  //==>output buffer
echo ... //==>output buffer
<?php header(...) ?>
```

this works:

```
<?php
session_start();
$some_variable=$_POST[];
$k="2";
//until here, nothing is send to the output buffer
header(...);
?>
<html>
```